# Show that an integral domain with every strictly decreasing chain of ideals $I_1 \supset I_2\supset \cdots $ finite in length is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show that an integral domain with the property that every strictly decreasing chain of ideals $I_1 \supset I_2\supset \cdots $ must be finite in length is a field.

**Attempt:** We need to show that every element in the integral domain $D$ is invertible. Let us suppose $\exists~ a \in D$ such that $a$ is not invertible.

Clearly, $ \langle a \rangle \supset \langle a^2 \rangle \supset\cdots \supset\langle a^n \rangle $ where $\langle a^{n } \rangle $ is the last ideal in the chain.

Now,   $\langle a^{n+1} \rangle $ should be equal to one of the  $\langle a^i \rangle ;~ 1 \leq i \leq n$

But $\langle a^{n+1} \rangle $ also satisfies $\langle a^n \rangle \supseteq \langle a^{n+1} \rangle $ and $\langle a^i \rangle \supset\langle a^n \rangle $

$\implies \langle a^j \rangle =\langle a^n \rangle ~~\forall~~j \geq n$

Now, since $a$ is not a unit, $\langle a  \rangle $ does not contain the unity and hence, $\langle a  \rangle \neq D$

How do I move forward and have I interpreted the problem correctly?

Thank you for your help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $a$ is not a unit, then $\langle a^{n+1} \rangle \ne \langle a^n \rangle$ because if $a^n \in \langle a^{n+1} \rangle$, i.e., $a^n = r a^{n+1}$ for some $r \in D$, then $a^n(1 - ra) = 0$, and that implies $1 = ra$ (because $D$ is a domain), contradicting the assumption that $a$ is not a unit.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. Makes me happy that I was indeed very close. I should have thought about this as well. :-)

Comment: @Tunococ:What is the example of such Integral domain??

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\langle a^n\rangle=\langle a^{n+1}\rangle\implies a^{n+1}\in\langle a^n\rangle\implies ??$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get this. I was indeed very close :-)